# Module pattern in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, dom, module

I'm practicing my JS skills (I'm new at it). I'm trying to get the specific element that triggered the event and display it in a `span` element. But I don't know what I'm doing wrong, when I click the button nothing happens.

This is for a calculator program that I'm doing but using module pattern I think it's called.

```
var Calculator = {
  init: function(){
    var button = document.querySelectorAll("[class^='button']");
    button.onclick = this.writeEvent;
  },
  write: function (element){
    document.getElementById("display").innerHTML = element;
  },
  writeEvent: function(event){
    write(target.event)
  }
}

Calculator.init();
```

Comment: Its `event.target`, please check the console next time before asking here ;)

Comment: Also, `button.onclick` won't work because `button` is a `NodeList` not an `Element`.

Answer (score 1):

There are several problems with the posted code.

---

> ```
>     var button = document.querySelectorAll("[class^='button']");
>     button.onclick = this.writeEvent;
> ```

The result of `querySelectorAll` is a `NodeList`.
Assigning to its `onclick` property will not achieve what you want.
You want to assign to the `onclick` property of each individual node.

But actually that's not so simple, we'll need to come back to this.

---

> ```
>   writeEvent: function(event){
>     write(target.event)
>   }
> ```

One problem here is that `target` is undefined.
Surely you meant `event.target`.

Another problem is that `write` is also undefined.
Perhaps you meant `this.write`,
but that won't actually work well.
The problem is that when `writeEvent` is called from a click event,
it won't be called on the object,
so `this` will not be bound to the calculator object,
and the `this.write` call will raise an exception.

There's a way to overcome this,
by binding the `onclick` handler function to the object when setting it.

---

Putting the above together:

```
var Calculator = {
  init: function() {
    var nodeList = document.querySelectorAll("[class^='button']");
    var callback = this.writeEvent.bind(this);
    nodeList.forEach(item => item.onclick = callback);
  },
  write: function(element) {
    document.getElementById("display").innerHTML = element;
  },
  writeEvent: function(event) {
    this.write(event.target);
  }
}

Calculator.init();
```